# Spawn Actor with a class (UE4)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm currently trying to spawn a trap in my scene with the function "Spawn Actor" but, oddly, it don't want to take my static class as a UClass*. So this line :

```
currentTrap = GetWorld()->SpawnActor(AOMFBallista::StaticClass, GetOwner()->GetActorLocation());
```

just does'nt want to work. The error is :

> 'AActor *UWorld::SpawnActor(UClass *,const FTransform *,const
>   FActorSpawnParameters &)' : unable to convert the argument 1 from
>   'UClass *(__cdecl *)(void)' to 'UClass
>   *'    OrcMustFry  D:\SVN\2018-2019\Sections\Prog3B\Cours\UE4\Application\OrcMustFry\Step3\Correction\Source\OrcMustFry\PlaceTrapComponent.cpp 36

If you have any idea of where this problem can come, I would be very grateful !

Comment: Looks like the first argument to ``SpawnActor`` should be a function pointer whose return type is ``* UClass`` and doesn't take any agument. But the argument that you are providing doesn't match it's signature

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering what this signature with "(__cdecl *)" was meaning, thank you very much :) !

Answer (score 0):

StaticClass is not a field, but a function. So you are missing the '()' at the end:

```
currentTrap = GetWorld()->SpawnActor(AOMFBallista::StaticClass(), GetOwner()->GetActorLocation());
```

Comment: You statement doesn't answer his question. The problem is something else. Look at the comments

Comment: The question is why it does not compile -> I answered with the corrected code that does compile and said what was missing. How is this not answering the question.
Also, "Laura" is not a men's name.